# Set geometry of listView's item in QComboBox

Tags: css, macos, qt

I am experiencing this problem where I have two QComboBox. One is editable. And another, non-editable.

I want to set the same stylesheet for both of them. Preferably, like the one in editable. How to set the position such that the item comes below the arrow.

The CSS is just an approach. Actually its the internal property of default Editable and Non-editable QComboBox.Apparently, the first line in editable Box is for adding new items (QLineEdit) which we don't have in the non-editable (ofcourse!) which changes the view. I have this approach that if, somehow, I find the internal QComboBox constructor and properties that Qt uses for its default QComboBox, I can customise it.   Please help me if I can find the same

The stylesheets used are as follows:

```
ui->editable->setStyleSheet("QComboBox:editable{height : 30px; background-color:white; color:black; border-radius: 2px;padding-left:1px; }QListView{background-color:white; selection-background-color:#3C8C3F; height : 30px;padding-bottom:7px;padding-top:7px;}");
```

-> Non-editable

```
 QListView * listView = new QListView(ui->demoEdit);
         ui->demoEdit->addItem("foo");
         ui->demoEdit->addItem("bar");
         ui->demoEdit->addItem("foobar");
         ui->demoEdit->addItem("fooooo");




         listView->setStyleSheet("QListView{background-color:white; selection-background-color:#3C8C3F;border-radius:0px;height :30px;padding-bottom:10px;padding-top:10px;padding-left:40pt;margin-top:30px;}");

        ui->demoEdit->setView(listView);

 ui->demoEdit->setStyleSheet("QComboBox{background-color:white; color:black;height:30px;width:20px;border:0px;}");
```

Editable ComboBox:- The 1st item starts below the arrow.

Non-Editable ComboBox:- The 1st item starts with the arrow.

[image: THIS IS EDITABLE]

[image: THIS IS NON-EDITABLE]

I am working on Mac.

Comment: Your CSS of `ui->editable` is working fine for me, with the listview starting below the combobox. Though I do not have the exact same look (Windows, Qt9.1) so maybe you have some other CSS conflicting with the one you copied here. The CSS of `ui->demoEdit` leaves a big blank in the listview before the 1st item, so it is not working fine as it is. The combobox being editable or not does not make a difference for the CSS behaviour from what I tested.

Comment: Sorry. I forgort to mention that I am working on mac. That is where the problem occurs.

Comment: Anway, I would advise to use the exact same CSS (and not making the QListView yourself if not really needed) to avoid the differences.

Answer (score 2):

I found a work-around to this.

I made the non-editable QComboBox checked as editable and then set the QLineEdit of QComboBox as ReadOnly.

```
 1. ui->nonEditComboBox->setEditable(true);

 2. QLineEdit *mylineEdit = ui->nonEditComboBox->lineEdit();  //make object of QLineEdit
    mylineEdit->setReadOnly(true);
```